# Loading lines coordinates via command line - custom input format

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I have to load coordinates via command line.

Coordinates are in format like this:

```
0 1 1 1  1 1 2 2  12 12 13 13  3 3 4 4
```

`first line coordinates are:`
`x1: 0 y1: 1`
`x2: 1 y2: 1`

`second line coordinates are:`
`x1: 1 y1: 1`
`x2: 2 y2: 2`
etc.

**What I tried?**

Tried to find 'double space' in input but it seems that it loads only numbers so I can not track if user for sure passed 4x coordinates of line (with this method user can pass `0 1  0 2  12 12 13 13` and it will pass and this is wrong):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    for(String s:args){
        if(s.equals("  "))
            System.out.println("double space");
            // never enters here
        else {
            System.out.println(" | " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to load all arguments as a new list but just realized that the problem is the same as above and I still can not properly track if user passes data in my template:

```
public void begin(String args[]) {
    rawArgs = new ArrayList<>();
    rawArgs.addAll(Arrays.asList(args));
    System.out.println(rawArgs);
}
```

So I would like to ask what do you think would be the best way to load this kind of data?

```
0 1 1 1  1 1 2 2  12 12 13 13  3 3 4 4
```

So that I can track if user for sure passed 4x coordinates for a single line. How can I track this double space?

**PS.** I thought about passing this data in quotes like this:

```
"0 1 1 1  1 1 2 2  12 12 13 13  3 3 4 4"
```

But not sure how can I properly and efficiently translate string into numbers.

Going forward:
I think of keeping this data as an array of arrays of ints[4], what do you think? it will be ok?

For instance:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> coordinates;
```

And `coordinates[0]` will have inside an array list `[0, 1, 1, 1]`

**I will appreciate any help!**

Comment: Found out that the best way to keep points is to use `HashSet` because it prevents duplicates of data so I can insert point `1, 1` from one line and point `1, 1` from other and it will merge in to a single point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would follow your second approach, which meant passing a string with coordinates as one argument (in quotes). It's usually simpler to work with single string than multiple arguments.

What I would do firstly is checking if the input matches regular expression which is always like:
`D D D D  D D D D  D D D D  D D D D`

It is as simple as it looks:

```
^\d+ \d+ \d+ \d+  \d+ \d+ \d+ \d+  \d+ \d+ \d+ \d+  \d+ \d+ \d+ \d+$
```

*(of course it could be shortened a bit, but let's keep it as simple as possible)*

Now you don't have to worry if the input you received is valid, so you can focus on parsing it. My idea was to iterate over the string divided by spaces, convert it to Integer and put together to the array. There are four groups of four coordinates, so as a result it is an ArrayList of four ArrayLists of four Integers.

Here is a piece of code I wrote:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "^\\d+ \\d+ \\d+ \\d+  \\d+ \\d+ \\d+ \\d+  \\d+ \\d+ \\d+ \\d+  \\d+ \\d+ \\d+ \\d+$";
        if(args.length != 1 || !args[0].matches(regex)) {
            System.out.println("Input format should be: \"0 1 1 1  1 1 2 2  12 12 13 13  3 3 4 4\"");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        var groups = args[0].split("  ");
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
        for(var group : groups) {
            var arrayOfStrings = group.split(" ");
            var coordinate = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(var singleString : arrayOfStrings) {
                coordinate.add(Integer.parseInt(singleString));
            }
            coordinates.add(coordinate);
        }

        //printing coordinates
        for(var singleGroup : coordinates) {
            System.out.println("[" + singleGroup.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")) + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 2]
[12, 12, 13, 13]
[3, 3, 4, 4]
```